# How to doplay a IFRAME in angular if the src come from dataBindings

Tags: angular

If i run the code having a LINK stright on the sourscode run perfect.

But if i fet the link by {{}} data bingings i have problems.

This is the code:

```
<iframe width="900" height="700"  src='{{link}}' frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Reporte Uno SafeValue must use [property]=binding:

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2+ you bind a value to an element attribute like this, supposing you have a variable `link`:

```
<iframe width="900" height="700"  [attr.src]="link" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```